# Assuming a person has water/ice magic, is it even semi-possible that they'd be able to create various light effects with their magic?

Tags: science-based, magic

Like, forming water into ice prisms and using those to perfectly reflect the light. Limits are that the water is just normal water, the ice is normal ice, and the light itself can't be changed (pretend the light is coming from the sun).

In theory you can do anything with the water/ice so long it doesn't change into another element (it can become mist, for example).

If so...how. Is the prism thing too crazy? "Every drop of water is controlled in such a way that the user can create various light effects (light pillars, rainbows, etc.)"?

Comment: Given that we don’t know what water or ice magic is capable of in your world, how do you expect us to be able to definitively answer this question.

Comment: Hello @cae, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. Please carefully read our [tour], [help/on-topic] and [help/dont-ask] to better understand our limits and requirements. Questions like this don't make a lot of sense. Our goal is to help you build an imaginary world. In your world, anything is possible! So the answer to a question like this is always, "yes!" But is that useful to you? We can help you design your magic system, but that means asking specific questions about your magic system. Do you have a specific question in mind?

Comment: @JBH made some edits. Hope they're clear!

Comment: @sphennings I thought the OP was clear from the jump; hope my edits further clarify 

Comment: Does “do anything” include create various light effects?

Comment: Since water in itself is capable of creating these various light effects, there is no reason why water controlled by magic couldn't do the same. It fully depends on how much control the magician has over the water to determine what they are capable of.

Comment: This [page](https://farbeinf.de/static_html/refraction.html) lists a few real-life effects that could well fit into your mage's abilities. As a side note, now I'm getting curious if one could create a high definition display on the sky, using 'only' an arbitrarily complex combination of water droplets and ice shapes suspended in just the right positions...

Comment: Hi @cae. No, adding that one sentence didn't help. If you think about it, what you're asking for is permission to use the idea ("Can I do this?") We love ideas! We love creativity! But the answer is still always yes. In your world, your magic system can manipulate water to create light effects - and that has a rational scientific basis. Is that all you needed to know? In other words, when asking future questions, don't ask for permission to use an idea. You already have that. If you feel like something won't work, explain why and ask how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 5):

**The Back of the Fridge is Warm**

[image]

The fridge makes stuff cold. The heat has to go somewhere. It goes into some pipes on the back. The pipes are warm to the touch. The heat leaks through the pipes to the outside of the fridge.

Your ice mages are super precise and fast fridges. They can suck the heat from a glass of water, in the blink of an eye, to make a  snowball. But the heat must go somewhere. I suggest the mage's rear end. Toot.

When the mage suddenly cools a large amount of water, the heat comes out as flame and light. The man below is a talented ice-mage. He has just turned a garbage pail of water into a snowman.

[image]

Of course this is a crude and impractical way to light your home. But it proves the concept works. The ice mages of your world have thousands of years to create something more sophisticated.

Comment: I wonder what creative process led the photographer to that picture

Comment: I believe there used to be a motorbike in the picture.

Comment: Upvote for the worship of snowmen on motorbikes.

Comment: I used that picture as a profile picture on social media ages ago :o (the man on it is not me btw)

Answer (score 4):

**Glowy as you want!**

Do you see that glowy fire?  That is water!

https://www.nasa.gov/returntoflight/system/system_SSME.html

[image: glowy fire!]

> As the Shuttle accelerates, the main engines burn a half-million
> gallons of liquid propellant provided by the large, orange external
> fuel tank. The main engines burn liquid hydrogen -- the second coldest
> liquid on Earth at minus 423 degrees Fahrenheit (minus 252.8 degrees
> Celsius) -- and liquid oxygen.
>
> The engines' exhaust is primarily water vapor as the hydrogen and
> oxygen combine.

If you heat up water it turns to a gas.  If you heat the gas even more it will glow.  It is flame!  That is what is shooting out the back of the space shuttle - glowing flames made of water.

It seems like heating up water should be within the scope of any water magic persons.  Maybe most water magicians can just boil eggs, with the most special ones making glowy flames.  Most special water magicians, not most special eggs.  Or maybe them too?   In any case when those flames cool down they will be invisible hot gas, then condense as fog, then little dewy water droplets.

--
Side note: prisms of ice particles is totally believable.  The sky gets full of those.  It seems like it would take more finesse to manipulate a skyfull of tiny particles than it would to make something so hot that it glows.  Different approaches to water magic maybe?

Ooo - third way to make light with water:  [sonoluminescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonoluminescence)

Comment: Well, the glowy fire isn't water, so much as it's aluminum oxide and carbon particles at extreme temperature.  The water exhaust from the main engines (which run on hydrogen and oxygen) is a nearly invisible flame.

Comment: You have mooted that aluminum exhaust before, @Zeiss Ikon.  This time I looked and linked NASA page I take to mean depicted exhaust is water.  Page does make a distinction between solid rocket booster (I assume the aluminum) and main engines (depicted; H2 and O2).

Comment: I would be interested in posting the issue (H2O exhaust: glowy?) on the space exploration stack.  Whomever turns out to be wrong shall open a chat room to host a 5 stanza poem composed by the loser in honor of the winner.

Comment: I'm not a member there, but it's easy to find video of the main engines (including the 4 RS-25 on SLS) starting up on the ground before the SRBs ignite..

Answer (score 2):

### It's possible, but not in the way you describe

To answer your first question, could ice prisms be used to display a rainbow? Yes, but not using the physics you described. The way you describe the process is this:

> Like, forming water into ice prisms and using those to perfectly reflect the light.

So... no.

This explanation shows a basic lack of understanding as to how prisms work.

> A [prism](https://wonders.physics.wisc.edu/prisms/#:%7E:text=A%20prism%20works%20because%20the,out%20instead%20of%20mixed%20up.) works because the different colors of light travel at different speeds inside the glass. Because the colors of light travel at different speeds, they get bent by different amounts and come out all spread out instead of mixed up.

The process of light getting "bent" is called **refraction**, in which light hits the prism at an angle, causing the wave to change direction. You use the term **reflection** to describe how your prisms work. But reflection is when the waves bounce off the surface at equal angles, meaning no rainbow is visible because the colors are not separated.

Theoretically, it is possible for water ice to ***refract*** light, even though this is not its normal behavior. [Sun dogs, halos, and sun pillars](https://www.weather.gov/arx/why_halos_sundogs_pillars) are all examples of ice being refracted in nature to create a rainbow.

So yes, your mage can manipulate ice to produce a light show. But first, they must understand the difference between reflection and refraction.

Another possibility for using water to create a lightshow is that created during a rainstorm or over Niagara Falls. In these cases, *liquid* water is being used. I suggest you check out that option as well.